# ConEmu не видит artisan (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Всем привет! Работаю через Open Server. phpStorm и консоль Open Server видит artisan. Почему ConEmu не видит artisan (Laravel)? Я уже успел и тут спросить
https://toster.ru/q/243609

Пишут "ConEmu не при чем. Убедитесь, что php-cli собран и сконфигурирован с поддержкой mbstring"

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded ('mbstring')){
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Answer (score 1):

В общем, копания привели к такому выводу.
Стандартная cmd.exe тоже не работает с artisan
На Open Server стоит в принципе такой же ConEmu, который работает с artisan и можно настроить цветные буковки :)
Но! Если добавить в "закладки" ConEmu и запускать из-под OpenServer -> вуаля, все заработало. Кстати, аналогичным образом нужно запускать и phpStorm

Comment: Переменные окружения проверяйте. В первую очередь `PATH`. Open Server их инициализирует перед запуском ConEmu.

Comment: @Деня Деня а всего лишь нужно было прочитать справку по openserverу